# Fourier transform of a function is square integrable

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Is there a result stating that if a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is square integrable and decays at infinity, then its Fourier transform is also square integrable?

Comment: You could leave out the condition that the function decays at infinity which is implied by the fact that it is square integrable.

Comment: @Garrett I recently learned of some contrived examples showing that that is not necessarily true (e.g. uniformly spaced rectangles with areas decreasing quickly enough to have a convergent integral).

Comment: @ArturodonJuan, I guess "decay at infinity" is not well-defined, but I was taking it to include the situation you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More is true: the Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, a fact often noted as [a corollary to the Fourier inversion formula (cf. Sec. 6)](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~web6130/lectureFT.pdf) by  invoking [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Parseval's.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @Columbo: Thanks, it looks like the first link was reorganized to [this location](http://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/content/files/fourier.pdf), but I will take the opportunity to replace it with a less verbose document.